# Using Gson instead of Jackson in Jersey

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jax-rs, jackson, gson

I have a RESTful service that consumes and produces JSON objects, and I would like Jersey to use Gson instead of Jackson.

How can this be done...?

Comment: Aside from how (which is answered), curious as to why? There are already 4 alternative methods. So what does Gson bring above and beyond Jackson and Jettison?

Comment: IMHO with Gson it's much easier to control the structure/format of the JSON if you can't or don't want to annotate the hell out of your model classes (compared to Jackson).

Comment: There are many reasons:
First of all, according to recent benchmarks, Jackson is slower.
Second, it enforces you to annotate classes, rather than simply use POJOs just the way they are.
Third, Gson serializes the entire object, and not just the public fields (as in good design practice, you get to have many important non-public fields).

Comment: @StaxMan One of the reasons could be that Jackson ObjectMapper causes core dump in JDK 1.8

Comment: @krzyk not that I won't believe you but I haven't seen reports of this; and without bug reports things can't be fixed. Nor are they credible complaints IMO.

Comment: @MosheBixenshpaner links please to slowness -- I have not seen any. Gson has been improving (2.1 is decent), but still lagging from all I have seen. Jackson absolute does not require annotations (plus, mix-in annotations can be used to avoid annotation value classes) for most cases. Last: Jackson does not require public fields; but either getters, or changing of default visibility -- I disagree in that serializing all private fields by default is good practice; but if one wants it, perfectly doable with Jackson.

Comment: @StaxMan See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8035399

Comment: This link might help you how to do serialize/deserializing using gson : http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/11/02/integrating-gson-into-a-jax-rs-based-application/

Comment: @StaxMan,

http://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/

Clearly, for the *average* object responses (~1k), GSON wins the competition.

Comment: @MosheBixenshpaner Please read comments at that measurement -- it is badly written, measuring noise if anything. I am not objecting to findings, but the flaws in measurement methodology. I have not seen anything credible to suggest GSON would be significantly faster than Jackson for messages of any size, although there are many cases where speed differences are negligible (within 10-20% range).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to write custom implementations of [`MessageBodyReader`](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) and [`MessageBodyWriter`](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) (possibly in the same class) and register with Jersey (if you use package scanning, the `@Provider` annotation is enough) -- pretty much like [`JacksonJsonProvider`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.2/org/codehaus/jackson/jaxrs/JacksonJsonProvider.java) does it:

```
@Provider
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json"})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json"})
class GsonJsonProvider implements
    MessageBodyReader<Object>,
    MessageBodyWriter<Object> { ...
```

Comment: I already have such a provider, but for some reason, it still uses  Jackson (I use Glassfish 3.1.1 if that helps).

Comment: How to you register your GsonProvider with Jersey? Does your server output something like `Provider classes found: your.provider.class.name` on startup?

Comment: Does your provider get invoked and maybe returns something that tells Jersey it's not compatible? Try adding breakpoints on all methods in your provider class.

Answer (score 21):

You can find a fully working example here: https://github.com/DominikAngerer/java-GsonJerseyProvider

There will be an working implementation of http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/11/02/integrating-gson-into-a-jax-rs-based-application/ but with some new achievements - like an `GsonUtil` for `Expose` only things.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class GsonJerseyProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<Object>,
        MessageBodyReader<Object> {

    private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            java.lang.annotation.Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(entityStream,
                UTF_8);
        try {
            return GsonUtil.getInstance().fromJson(streamReader, genericType);
        } catch (com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException e) {
            // Log exception
        } finally {
            streamReader.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
            OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException,
            WebApplicationException {
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream, UTF_8);
        try {
            GsonUtil.getInstance().toJson(object, genericType, writer);
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Been using this, works great but... why the `type.equals(genericType)` ? Seems to be that you can always use `Type` as gson supports it and has more information than the `Class<Object>`.

Comment: You're right - the `genericType` should be used instead of the equals check - you can create a pull request on github if you like. I also will test it with my test cases as well and then edit my answer.

Comment: thanks @sargue for the update of the GsonJerseyProvider - I have updated the copy&paste solution in here - you can find a running example directly under the github link.

Answer (score 3):

### Payara 4

I had a hard time to get my custom Gson `@Provider` working with Jersey embedded in GlassFish / Payara. In that case you must set the property `jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson` to `true`.

For example:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson", true);
        return props;
    }
}
```

See also:

- https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/appendix-properties.html
- [Customizing JSON marhsalling with GlassFish v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054821/customizing-json-marhsalling-with-glassfish-v4)

Same thing goes for a Jersey client:

```
new ClientConfig()
        .register(MyGsonProvider.class)
        .property("jersey.config.client.disableMoxyJson", true);
```

### Payara 5

Payara 5 supports the [JSON Binding](https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/) API, so it does not make sense to keep using Gson. I would advice to migrate to JSON-B.

Answer (score 1):

You should solve just adding this dependency in your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zalando.phrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-gson</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here you can find the repo with the source code: https://github.com/zalando/jersey-media-json-gson

Comment: project no longer exists in github

Answer (score 1):

one eternity later....
You can use the real dependency jersey media gson

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-gson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

the class to registrer is:

```
JsonGsonFeature.class
```