# Amadeus SDK with quarkus

Tags: java, gson, quarkus, amadeus

I am trying to use `Amadeus SDK` with `quarkus`. I have run the SDK with `Spring Boot` and the API works fine. The requirement for the `Amadeus SDK` is to use `GSON` as the JSON mapping library. So below configuration was necessary in `Spring Boot`.

```
spring.mvc.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson
```

But I couldn't find how to use `GSON` with `quarkus`. There is no `resteasy-client-gson` extension available for `quarkus` due to which I am getting below exception when using the Amadeus Java SDK.

```
Could not write JSON: JsonObject; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.amadeus.resources.FlightOfferSearch[0]->com.amadeus.resources.FlightOfferSearch["response"]->com.amadeus.Response["result"]->com.google.gson.JsonObject["asBoolean"]
```

Is there any way to resolve this and and configure `GSON` as Json mapping library for `Amadeus SDK` with `quarkus`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in GSON extension in Quarkus, but you can make Quarkus use GSON for the REST API layer by implementating a GSON based `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter`.

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9518404/2504224) answer for more details